# Pagination for facebook using javascript

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to get the next page results from facebook on a particular topic for my application.
I am able to extract the recent comments from a facebook page, but not able to do so for getting the next page of results.I am using javascript for the same.

Can anyone help me out in this regard.

Thanks in advance
Sonnali Sahoo

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).paged_scroll({
    handleScroll:function (page,container,doneCallback) {
        yourLogic.getData(function(data){
          var html = yourLogic.parseData(data);
          $('#element').append(html);
        });
    },
    triggerFromBottom:'10px',
    targetElement : $('#element')
    loader:'<div class="loader">Loading next page ...</div>',
    pagesToScroll: yourLogic.totalNumberOfPages
});
```

Your have complete documentation and a plenty of examples on: `Github.
https://github.com/dimaxweb/jquery-paged-scroll`